# from LOOKUP function to VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, function, vlookup, lookup

I'm trying to use VLOOKUP excel function instead of LOOKUP.
I've read VLOOKUP is well optimized but I'm not able to adjust it.
Any help please?

Following function return:

- 1 if first condition met is >
- -1 if first condition met is <

`=LOOKUP(2,1/((E1:E9>E10)-(E1:E9<E10)))`

Scope of function is: looking to E10 value, searching on range E1:E9 starting from bottom to top, if firstly appear a number > or < of E10, returning +1 or -1

Example 1

```
E1 = 6
E2 = 5
E3 = 5
E4 = 4
E5 = 6
E6 = 6
E7 = 5
E8 = 8
E9 = 8
```

> If E10 = 8

Result is -1 because first value found is smaller than E10 (starting from E9 and going up)

> If E10 = 7

Result is 1 because first value found is bigger than E10 (starting from E9 and going up)

??

```
=VLOOKUP(2,1/((E1:E9>E10)-(E1:E9<E10));1)
```

or any other function instead of LOOKUP?

Comment: can you mock up some data and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning to my first function:

`=LOOKUP(2,1/((E1:E9>E10)-(E1:E9<E10)))`

I've scomposed it, to understand how it works, to find others possible solutions.

- Firstly Excel convert my condition into **TRUE** and **FALSE**

> IF E10=8

`=LOOKUP(2,1/((FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)-(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE)))`

- Next it converts **TRUE** and **FALSE** into **1** and **0**

`=LOOKUP(2,1/((0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)-(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0)))`

- Next it makes "**-**" operation obtaining:

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0))`

- Next it converts into arrays:

`=LOOKUP(2,{-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,#Div/0!,#Div/0!},ROW(E1:E9))`

- Next converts also `ROW(E1:E9)` into arrays obtaining:

`=LOOKUP(2,{-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,#Div/0!,#Div/0!},{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})`

- To conclude looks from **bottom** to **top** of range, searching for a value close to `2`, returnig `-1` because `E7=5` and is smaller than `E10=8`

**So now, understanding how Excel elaborates is possible to use following function to obtain arrays:**

`=INDEX(1/((E1:E9>E10)-(E1:E9<E10)),0)`

resulting in the same:

`{-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,#Div/0!,#Div/0!}`

and using previous result combined with **VLOOKUP**, to get same result of **LOOKUP** function, but accepting it whitout **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER** that was my goal

`=VLOOKUP(2,INDEX(1/((E1:E9>E10)-(E1:E9<E10)),0),1)`

Answer (score 0):

Previous supposed solution works correctly

```
=VLOOKUP(2,1/((E1:E9>E10)-(E1:E9<E10));1)
```

but formula needs to be entered with:

```
CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER
```

I've tried with MATCH but to me result to don't work correctly.

Any other ideas?